Discord.js dont listen on on_message event
I am trying make bot, that will delete mesages. Problem is that randomly bot stops listening messages and I dont know why. May it be request limit, but after start bot send message in channel, but dont listen.

Bot will send "Ready", but dont listening on messages

Could it be problem with permissions? Or some type of API limit?
//client
const client = new DISCORD.Client({
   intents:[
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageReactions,
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
       DISCORD.IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageTyping
   ],
   partials: [
       DISCORD.Partials.Channel,
       DISCORD.Partials.DirectMessages,
       DISCORD.Partials.Message,
       DISCORD.Partials.Reaction
   ]
});

client.on(DISCORD.Events.ClientReady, async client => {
   console.log('Bot is running')
   client.guilds.cache.get('guild_id').channels.fetch('channel_id').then(channel=>channel.send('Ready!'))
   bot_mention = client.user.toString()
});

client.on(DISCORD.Events.Message, async (message) => {
   console.log(message.channel.name)
   if (message.author.bot) return
   if (!message.content.startsWith(bot_mention)) return
   message.content=message.content.slice(bot_mention.length+1)
   COMMANDS.forEach(async command => {
       if (message.content.startsWith(command.command)){
           message.content=message.content.slice(command.command.length)
           await command.execute(message)
       }
   })
})

client.login("TOKEN");


You are listening to an event that will never be fired by your Discord bot.
The correct event listener for newly created messages would be DISCORD.Events.MessageCreate.
Here's a link for discord.js v14 documentation with a list of all available event listeners. Click
